# `block in activate_dependencies': can't satisfy 'windows-pr (= 1.2.1)', already activated 'windows-pr-1.2.2' (Gem::LoadError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, vagrant

I'm trying to use http://rove.io/ to setup a vagrant box on my Windows 8 machine. I've followed the instructions on the site (specifically to install `gem install librarian-chef` and run `librarian-chef install`, but I'm getting the following error:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:774:in `block in activate_dependencies': can't satisfy 'windows-pr (= 1.2.1)', already activated 'windows-pr-1.2.2' (Gem::LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:766:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:766:in `activate_dependencies'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:750:in `activate'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:780:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:766:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:766:in `activate_dependencies'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:750:in `activate'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1232:in `gem'
    from C:/Ruby193/bin/librarian-chef:22:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had exactly this problem.  Windows 8.1 professional, Ruby193.

First I looked at uninstalling windows-pr 1.2.1, but chef has a dependency on it

```
chef-11.6.2 depends on [windows-pr (= 1.2.1)]
```

I decided to uninstall the newer version windows-pr version 1.2.2.

```
>gem uninstall windows-pr -v1.2.2

You have requested to uninstall the gem:
        windows-pr-1.2.2
mixlib-shellout-1.2.0 depends on [windows-pr (~> 1.2.2)]
win32-dir-0.3.7 depends on [windows-pr (>= 1.0.9)]
win32-process-0.6.5 depends on [windows-pr (>= 1.1.2)]
win32-service-0.7.2 depends on [windows-pr (>= 1.0.8)]
If you remove this gems, one or more dependencies will not be met.
Continue with Uninstall? [Yn]  Y
Successfully uninstalled windows-pr-1.2.2
```

It looked like the only dependency I had that would cause a problem was mixlib-shellout 1.2.0.  I decided to fall back a version to see if that would fix it.

```
>gem uninstall mixlib-shellout

You have requested to uninstall the gem:
        mixlib-shellout-1.2.0-x86-mingw32
chef-11.6.2 depends on [mixlib-shellout (~> 1.1)]
ohai-6.18.0 depends on [mixlib-shellout (>= 0)]
If you remove this gems, one or more dependencies will not be met.
Continue with Uninstall? [Yn]  Y
Successfully uninstalled mixlib-shellout-1.2.0-x86-mingw32

>gem install mixlib-shellout -v1.1.0

Fetching: mixlib-shellout-1.1.0-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Fetching: windows-pr-1.2.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mixlib-shellout-1.1.0-x86-mingw32
Successfully installed windows-pr-1.2.2
2 gems installed
Installing ri documentation for mixlib-shellout-1.1.0-x86-mingw32...
Installing ri documentation for windows-pr-1.2.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for mixlib-shellout-1.1.0-x86-mingw32...
Installing RDoc documentation for windows-pr-1.2.2...
```

and that seemed to fix it

```
>librarian-chef init

      create  Cheffile
```